# Find and replace first digit with notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have a bunch of numbers like this:

```
001
001
002
002
002
003
003
003
003
```

all the way up to 100. using the search and replace
is there a way to just change the first number so that i could get it up to 1000 faster?

I am also open to any other ideas.

Comment: I don't understand the output you're after.  Can you show what you would like `001 001 002 002 002 003 003 003 003....` to be replaced with?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to add "1" replacing the first number witch would be 101 101 102 102 102 102 and so on.

Comment: So `001 001 002 002 002 003 003 003 003` would become `101 101 102 102 102 103 103 103 103`?  Or would it become `101 001 002 002 002 003 003 003 003`?

Comment: it would become 101 101 102 102 102 103 103 103 103 all the way up to 199.

Comment: Would it not accomplish what you want to search for ` 0` and replace with ` 1`?  (Note the leading spaces)

Comment: no my numbers are in columns with no space in fount of them but I see what you were getting at.

Comment: Search for a `^0` regex and replace it with `1`.

Comment: ...or highlight from the end of one line through the first `0` on the next, hit ctl-c (copy) then hit ctl-f (find).  Paste into the find box and into the replace with box, then change the `0` in the replace with box to a `1.`

Comment: You could also do this with extended search and replace instead of Regular Expression mode.  Find `\r\n0` replace with `\r\n1`.  Turning on display of all characters (the double-struck backwards P) may help you understand what is going on there.  In windows, you'll see every line is ended with a **cr lf**  **cr** is \r and **lf** is \n.

Comment: Thanks for helping me figure this out I was really stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to just change the first number?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `[0-9]([0-9])([0-9])`
- Set "Replace with" to `1\1\2`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

```
001
001
002
002
002
003
003
003
003
```

**After**:

```
101
101
102
102
102
103
103
103
103
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)